# Java Program to display name in a right triangle?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Hi i want to make a program that displays the name in a right triangle form but I the other side output of this program is

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class NameGame2 {   
    public static void main(String[]args)   
    {  
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);   
        String name, name2 = "";   
        System.out.print("What is your name : ");   
        name = x.nextLine();   
        System.out.println();   
        for(int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {   
            name2 = name2 + name.charAt(i);   
            System.out.println(name2);   
        } System.out.print("\n");  
    }   
}
```

---

```
  I want the output to be like this        outputof my code is
       R                                   A
      ER                                   AS
     HER                                   ASH
    SHER                                   ASHE
   ASHER                                   ASHER
```

Comment: please post the correct code that you tried?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class NameGame2 {
public static void main(String[]args) {

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
String name, name2 = "";

System.out.print("What is your name : ");
name = x.nextLine();

System.out.println();

for(int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {
                name2 = name2 + name.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(name2);
        }
           System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

}
}

Comment: @singhakash here is the full

Comment: Could you please put that in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this you need a loop for space and character should start from last index.Full Code

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.print("What is your name : ");
String name = x.nextLine();
System.out.println();
for (int i = name.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
    System.out.print(" ");

    for (int j = i; j <= name.length() - 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(name.charAt(j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

output

```
     R
    ER
   HER
  SHER
 ASHER
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/yRf9p8)

Answer (score 1):

Java-8 solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class NameGame2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("What is your name : ");
        String name = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, name.length())
            .mapToObj(pos -> String.format("%" + name.length() + "s",
                             name.substring(name.length() - pos)))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```